# Is there any pre-commit validation to validate existence of comments/java-docs for the code before committing to SVN?

Tags: java, android, svn, android-studio, svncommit

Does it has to do with `Android Studio` ? what If some one using other `GUI` for `SVN`?

Comment: Fire them if they do not "write comments/java-docs for the code before committing to SVN".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about employee management and corporate policies.

Comment: @CommonsWare I wish, I could. BTW got your point, but I was just curious if I can add some validations for commit.

Comment: Well, as Gavin points out, you have no good way of automatically enforcing *well-written* comments. Putting automated checks in that do not really solve the problem seems like a waste of effort.

Comment: With Git you can use something like [Gerrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrit_%28software%29) to allow team members to review, approve or reject each others changes. So the team can enforce standards.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, CommonsWare. But I really don't see any reasons for the down votes.

Comment: @greg-449 this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is a little wider. While you might be able to compele somebody to add a commit message either through policy (with penalties such as formal warnings etc), or perhaps SVN has pre-commit hooks; would the messages be useful and meaningful?

Perhaps making sure you do peer reviews and education is the way to solve this issue.

Comment: @Mr.India you're welcome.

Comment: One thing we do when committing is to include the ticket number that the work was for as the first part of the message, something like "[MyProject-42] adding validation for x y or z"

Comment: I had an additional thought, if you are developing on branches (and you probably should be) you can refuse to merge the branch if there are commits without messages.  I believe you can edit commit messages fairly easterly in SVN.  Of course this requires the whole team to be of the same opinion with regard to commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is responsibility of team lead or project manager, when he/she assigns a project to team then a project manager/lead have to order his/her team to write comments before committing code on SVN

Comment: "Other w"..... what?

Comment: I would say it is the responsibility of the whole team